# How many points of Benefit to be President of the United States?

Tags: character-creation, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

How many points in the Benefit advantage would you need to be President of the United States (or the leader of a similarly powerful nation, like Russia or an alternate universe United States or something) in Mutants and Masterminds 3e? The Advantage itself says the following:

> - Diplomatic Immunity: By dint of your diplomatic status, you cannot be
>     prosecuted for crimes in nations other than your own. All another
>     nation can do is deport you to your home nation.
> - Security Clearance: You have access to classified government
>     information, installations, and possibly equipment and personnel.
> - Status: By virtue of birth or achievement, you have special status.    Examples include nobility, knighthood, aristocracy, and so forth.
> - Wealth: You have greater than average wealth or material resources,    such as Well-off (rank 1), Independently Wealthy (rank 2), Millionaire (rank 3), Multimillionaire (rank 4), or Billionaire (rank 5).

Presumably, "being the President" could fall under all of those categories. When I looked up Lex Luthor's writeup in DC Heros Adventures (which uses the same system), it mentions that at one point he runs for US President and wins, and his stat block gives him "Benefit 5 (wealth and resources)", though I'm not sure if that is for him running LexCorp, him running the country as President, or both.

Does anyone have any hard rules for this? Ideally it'd involve a statblock of a reigning monarch or a sitting President, or an explicit rules statement somewhere, but something like a developer comment somewhere or rules from previous editions would work too (if they're compatible with what 3e says).

Comment: Can you post Luthor's write-up (or part of it) for clarification? From your description, it isn't clear how connected the presidency and "Benefit 5 (wealth and resources)" pieces are. I haven't seen the book, but from the comics Lex Luthor almost certainly has the Billionaire trait independent of being President.

Comment: @BenS The only other Advantages Lex Luthor has that might be directly related to being President are the Connected and Well-Informed advantages, but both of those might also relate to his abilities to call in favors as a billionaire or just being a super-genius, rather than having the resources of a country to call for help with and a security apparatus that can give you security briefings; the Benefit I quoted is the only Benefit he has. As for the fluff section, it just says that he ran for President and won, then goes right on to describing how he then tried to frame Batman for murder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at Aquaman’s Benefit (DC is the only book I have available), his being King of Atlantis is only a 3.  Darkseid’s, for being Lord of Apokolips, is a 10.  Vandal Savage has a similar Benefit to Lex with Wealth and Resources, so it would seem that Lex’s Benefit does not include being President.